# How to say "match anything until a specific character, then work your way backwards"?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am often faced with patterns where the part which is interesting is delimited by a specific character, the rest does not matter. A typical example:

```
/dev/sda1       472437724  231650856 216764652  52% /
```

I would like to extract `52` (which can also be `9`, or `100` - so 1 to 3 digits) by saying *"match anything, then when you get to `%` (which is unique in that line), see before for the matches to extract"*.

I tried to [code this](https://regex101.com/r/gGzS8m/1/) as `.*(\d*)%.*` but the group is not matched:

- `.*` match anything, any number of times
- `%` ... until you get to the litteral `%` (the `\d` is also matched by `.*` but my understanding is that once `%` is matched, the regex engine will work backwards, **since it now has an "anchor"** on which to analyze what was before -- please tell if this reasoning is incorrect, thank you)
- `(\d*)` ... and now before that `%` you had a `(\d*)` to match and group
- `.*` ... and the rest does not matter (match everything)

Comment: You match nothing because the digits are optional. Try using a word boundary or match a space before `^.*\b(\d+)%.*` https://regex101.com/r/niKGIX/1

Comment: What about \w*% ?

Comment: (\d{1,3})% should be enough

Comment: I am not sure it’s relevant in your case, but I had to solve a similar “backwards” problem.  What I ended up doing was reversing the string and then writing a regex that operated on the reversed string.  Worked very well as the particular data structure was easier to parse right to left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex does not work because `.` matches too much, and the group matches too little. The group `\d*` can basically match *nothing* because of the `*` quantifier, leaving everything matched by the `.`.

And your description of `.*` is somewhat incorrect. It actually matches everything until the end, and moves backwards until the thing after it (`(\d*).*`) matches. For more info, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

In fact, I think your text can be matched simply by:

```
(\d{1,3})%
```

And getting group 1.

The logic of "keep looking until you find..." is kind of baked into the regex engine, so you don't need to explicitly say `.*` unless you want it in the match. In this case you just want the number before the `%` right?

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking to extract just the number then I would use:

```
import re
pattern = r"\d*(?=%)"
string = "/dev/sda1   472437724  231650856 216764652  52% /"
returnedMatches = re.findall(pattern, string)
```

The regex expression does a positive look ahead for the special character

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern this part `.*` matches until the end of the string. Then it backtracks giving up as least as possible till it can match 0+ times a digit and a `%`.

The `%` is matched because matching 0+ digits is ok. Then you match again `.*` till the end of the string. There is a capturing group, only it is empty.

What you might do is add a word boundary or a space before the digits:

`.* (\d{1,3})%.*` or `.*\b(\d{1,3})%.*`

[Regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/l5hjy8/1) Or [regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/l5hjy8/2)

Note that using `.*` (greedy) you will get the last instance of the digits and the `%` sign.

If you would make it non greedy, you would match the first occurrence:

```
.*?(\d{1,3})%.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l5hjy8/3)

Answer (score 1):

By default regex matches as greedily as possible. The initial `.*` in your regex sequence is matching everything up to the `%`:

```
"/dev/sda1       472437724  231650856 216764652  52"
```

This is acceptable for the regex, because it just chooses to have the next pattern, `(\d*)`, match 0 characters.

In this scenario a couple of options could work for you. I would most recommend to use the previous spaces to define a sequence which "starts with a single space, contains any number of digits in the middle, and ends with a percentage symbol":

```
' (\d*)%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.*(\b\d{1,3}(?=\%)).*
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/trzUIy/1)